# CSS: Image appear beside content area(left&right)

Tags: css

I am currently working with images and backgrounds css positions. I have been struggling trying to get the same image appear beside(left/right) the the content area. I am trying to have the image position not be affected with pagee re size .

How can i get the same picture to appear beside the content area? [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test/)

This what I am aiming for:

[image: This is What I am aiming for]

Comment: Could you post a simplified version of your site on http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [my stab at it](http://tinkerbin.com/HG4t3vbB). I used an absolutely positioned div positioned in the center to contain the images and then used position relative to get them to specific pixel positions to either side. The trick is that if you don't use relative positioning, they are on top of one another so you have to apply a `top:` equivalent to the height of the image to one of them to get it to shift to match.

HTML:

```
    <div id="image_container">
        <div id="img_r" class="outside_image">
            <img />
        </div>
        <div id="img_l" class="outside_image">
            <img />
        </div>  
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#image_container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0px;
  z-index: 900; /* not really required */
}

.outside_image img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.outside_image {
    position: relative;
}
#img_r{
  float: right;
  right: -725px;
  top: 200px;
}
#img_l{
  float: left;
  left: -725px;
}
```

Comment: +1 thank you. This seems to work but my image is 720 X 360 and I changed it this in the css `.outside_image img` but it knocks it out of proportion. And yes you are right about: `the content to always stay in the center and the images can slide off screen.`

Comment: if you don't want to scale your image at all you can remove that css completely and it will appear at whatever size the image that you provide is, you just have to make sure all images are scaled if you are using various images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative margin-left on #left2:

```css
#left2 {    
    float: left;    
    width: 200px;    
    background: #DDD;    
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;    
    border-radius: 10px;    
    margin-right: 15px;   
    padding: 5px;    
    margin-left: -248px;    
}
```

If you need it to stay in the same place you (even if you resize the page) you could use an absolute position:

```css
#left2 {   
    position: absolute;    
    left: 20px;   
    top: 160px;   
}
```

I use Chrome developer tools to try this stuff out btw. Here's a screenshot of your page with my code: 
http://d.pr/i/wXQ2

Comment: This doesn't put an image on the right side and it will cause problems with page resizing

Comment: the **position:absolute** solution won't be affected by page resizing.

Comment: really? If you resize the screen smaller, the image will always be visible. I presume he wants the content to always stay in the center and the images can get slide off screen.